# Errors when using two Asynchronous ASIHTTP Requests in different classes

Tags: ios, ios4

Suppose i have two classes A & B. class A calls the asynchronus method Foo in class B. Foo method fetches data using asynchronous ASIHTTPRequest and send the data from Foo back as the return value to Class A. Class A will use that returned data and do the things

I am creating a object of my class URLParser here in another class and calling the function getJsonUrl , it will parse and get the json url for me . I am using that returned URL in another ASIHTTPRequest here . But i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS ...help me to figure it out ....

```
......
URLParser *urlParser = [[URLParser alloc] init];

NSString *JsonString = [urlParser getJsonUrl:@"http://mywebs.com/?q=iphone/news"];
NSLog(@" url returned = %@" ,JsonString);
NSURL *JsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:JsonString];

newsRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:JsonUrl];
[newsRequest setDelegate:self];
[newsRequest startAsynchronous];

}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    newsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
    self.newsDictionary = [response JSONValue];
    [response release];
    [self getDataNews:self.newsDictionary];    
}
```

### URL Parser Class

```
@synthesize albumDic;
@synthesize GlobalRequest;

-(NSString*)getJsonUrl:(NSString *)url{

 GlobalRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 [GlobalRequest setDelegate:self];
 [GlobalRequest startAsynchronous]; // when i called the  [GlobalRequest startSynchronous] ....both cases m getting the same error

 return JsonStr;
}



- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

 albumDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
 NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
 self.albumDic = [response JSONValue];
 [response release];
 [self GetDictionary:self.albumDic];

}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
 [request cancel];

}
```